# Can databinding in WPF be done simply with a dataview like in winforms?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, winforms

Short and simple question. In Winforms you can bind a dataview to a combobox or some other control by simply:

```
combobox.DataSource = dataview
combobox.DisplayMember = "Something"
```

In WPF I've generally done databinding using an ObservableCollection and edits to the xaml. Is there a way to quickly do it, like the above?

Edit:
This seems to be the simplest/quickest thing I can come up with, anything inherently wrong with it?

```
combobox.ItemSource = dataview
combobox.DisplayMemberPath = "Something"
```

Comment: You're shortchanging yourself by doing it this way. Doing it properly with INotifyPropertyChanged and ObserveableCollections will make a huge difference for you. It's a little more complicated to implement, but it'll simplify things for you in the long run and is much more powerful.

Comment: @Yatrix appreciate the input, databinding is far from my specialty, but could you elaborate what you mean when you say it's more powerful and will simplify things in the long run?

Comment: If you use the interface and collection I mentioned, when you change any item's property in your collection, it will automatically update the items in the UI. This means you won't have to manually manage edits or UI updates, which simplifies the long-run outlook of managing your data presentation. In general, using WPF like a winform is pointless. WPF offers a lot of features winforms don't, much of which can be done in the mark-up with some know-how. It's really an awesome tool to use, but it IS a big adjustment from winforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set binding programmatically, although, per my understanding of the MVVM pattern, the best practice is to set binding in the View (xaml) not the ViewModel or View code-behind.

How to set binding programmatically:

```
Binding myBinding = new Binding("Name");
myBinding.Source = dataview // data source from your example

combobox.DisplayMemberPath = "Something"
combobox.SetBinding(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, myBinding);
```

With this, when your dataview is updated, the updates will be shown in your ComboBox.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
List<Person> someListOFPersons = new List<Person>();
comboBox.DataContext = someListOfPersons;
comboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "FirstName";
```

You will not see changes in the collection. So if a person is added to or removed from the list the combobox will not see it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I think I may have found something even simpler. Since I want a dataview, I can just set the ItemSource to the dataview, and then DisplayMemberPath

Comment: I just picked List<T> as an example, you can bind anything.